# How to control who can use my Tor Exit-Relay

Tags: ip, tor

I'm running a Exit-Relay from VMware-Ubuntu 16.04 and my Exit-Relay works great-i have all the flags that i need- `Exit, Fast, HSDir, Running,Stable,V2Dir, Valid.`
now i want to control my Exit-Relay and allow access to the people i want or deny it from the people i don't want.
i used `iptables` for it and its not working.
is there any way to do that?

one more:
i can set in my `torrc` file to use my Exit-Relay, or my Tor-Bridge. but, they are not working together because they both running from the same ip-ssh.
is there a way to set them to still run?
i know its not the meaning of the tor but still i want to do that

Comment: If you want to run an exit, you have to accept that it can relay traffic for anyone who uses Tor however they want to use it.  You can only control networks/ports that you don't want to be an exit to.  Since your exit relay doesn't know the actual IP of who's using it you can't allow some people to use it and others not to.

Comment: @drew010 thank you for your answer. but im still searching for way to do that.

Comment: How do you define "people you want to allow"?  Are these IP addresses, destination websites?  Remember, your exit doesn't know the client it's relaying traffic for.

Comment: I can allow to the IP's the i want to let them use my exit node and all the rest i can block. @drew010

Comment: Remember, because Tor is an anonymity system, you have no way of knowing the IP address of who is using your exit, nor would blocking it do anything.  All traffic going through your exit relay is coming from another relay on the Tor network on behalf of an anonymous user.  The only exit traffic you can block is by destination IP, and the proper way to do it would be through your [ExitPolicy](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitPolicy) and not using iptables.  Reject all outbound traffic, and then only allow outbound exit traffic to netblocks you allow.